# Toggle between child views with ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to render a view that toggles between two of its children (or so I'd hope) and something is not exactly working. Here is my template:

```
{{#view App.LoginFormView isVisibleBinding="user.isNotAuthenticated" }}
Username: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="user.loginName"}} / 
Password: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="user.userPassword" type="password"}}
<button class="btn" {{ action "login" }} {{bindAttr disabled="user.isNotValid"}}>Login</button>
{{/view}}

{{#view App.LoginInfoView isVisibleBinding="user.isAuthenticated" }}
You are logged in as {{user.loginName}}. Click <a {{action "logout"}}>here</a> to logout
{{/view}}
```

in app.js I have the following:

```
App.User = Ember.Object.extend({
    loginName:'',
    userPassword:'',
    rememberMe:true,
    isNotValid:function(){
        return (this.get("loginName") == '') || (this.get("userPassword") == '');
    }.property('loginName', 'userPassword'),
    isAuthenticated:false,
    isNotAuthenticated:function(){
        return !this.isAuthenticated;
    }.property('isAuthenticated')
});

App.AuthenticationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    login:function() {
        alert("loginName:"+this.user.get('loginName')+";\n"+
              "userPassword:"+this.user.get('userPassword')+";\n"+
          "rememberMe:"+this.user.get('rememberMe')+";\n");
        this.user.isAuthenticated = true;
    },
    user:App.User.create()
});
App.AuthenticationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'authentication',
    userBinding:"App.AuthenticationController.user"
});

App.LoginFormController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    userBinding:"App.AuthenticationController.user"
});
App.LoginFormView = Ember.View.extend();

App.LoginInfoController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    userBinding:"App.AuthenticationController.user"
});
App.LoginInfoView = Ember.View.extend();

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    enableLogging:true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router){
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('authentication','authentication');
            },
            login:function(router){
                router.get('authenticationController').login();
            }
        })
    })
});
```

The problem I am having is that the view does not toggle on the change of isAuthenticated property. I was under impression that would happen automagically and yet it does not. Any ideas on how to make this work? Or am I missing something fundamental (ember.js newbie here, so be gentle :-))

Cheers,
Alex.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Router Primer](http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/).

Comment: I did and no it does not help.

Comment: What is the current state of this? I mean, do both views get displayed at the same time? Also, are those view templates being rendered inside of another view template (like a parent view?), if that's the case, you might wanna change your binding to something like `isVisibleBinding="parentView.user.isNotAuthenticated"` when the object you're binding to is coming from the parent view. I believe this `parentView` has to be used since 1.0pre or pre2 for these cases

Comment: Could you try `this.set('user.isAuthenticated', true');` instead of `this.user.isAuthenticated = true;` in the AuthenticationController

Answer (score 0):

You can implement user authentication in the following way:

In your template (for example in `_header.hbs` templates which is a partial for `application.hbs`)

```
{{#if needAuth}}
    // login form goes here
    <button {{action submitLogin}}>login</button>
{{else}}
    <small {{action logout}}>logout</small>
{{/if}}
```

In application controller:

```
submitLogin: function () {
    // do login stuff

    // if login success
    that.set('needAuth', false);
    // else
    that.set('needAuth', true);
});
```

DOM will update automatically. In other partial templates you can use `{{#if needAuth}}` as well.